Blazor Server 8 Advanced Navigation Font Awesome icons oversized
I'm experiencing issues with Font Awesome and Blazor Server 8 when using advanced navigation. I created a new basic application and placed one icon from the FontAwesome package on the homepage. When I start the application, it looks fine:

Then I choose "Counter," and when I go back to "Home," it looks like this:

I have to do a hard refresh, and then it looks good again. If you repeat this process, go back to "Counter" and back to "Home," the icon is oversized again. I have read this post https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51696 , but I can't get this to work.
In my app.razor i have
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Blfont.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <script src=https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxx.js crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

My home.razor looks like:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<i class="fas fa-home"></i>

There are no errors in the browser console or in the .NET console
Is there an working example available, or can someone help me to fix this?

You forgot to put in your code. Also is there any error in the console?

indeed, sorry for that, i have updated the post, there are no errors

You still need to include home.razor code, reminder: do not post code as images.

thx already for you help, i have changed the post and added the code

I faced the same problem. I found two solutions, both using the downloaded package (self-hosted), instead of a linked CDN.
The first solution is to only use the webfont, without Javascript, and include this in your application. Copy the webfonts directory and the all.css (or fontawesome.css together with solid.css) to the application resource library. I've place mine in wwwroot\lib\fontawesome\. Link the css-file(s) in the app.razor, and the css-file will include the webfonts. This solution works, but it using the resizing tags such as fa-xl or fa-xs do not work, as those need Javascript.
The alternative is to disable "Blazor's enhanced navigation", which causes issues because the Javascript to process Fontawesome after a navigation action, does not run. To do this, you need to add data-enhance-nav="false" in the <html> or <body> tags of your page. You see that each page is then loaded completely after a navigation action, instead of refreshing the dynamic content. Also this solution does not seem to work with different sizes.
